# Reshape 1D arrays to meshgrid format

Tags: arrays, matlab, reshape

I have the data `x`,`y`,`z` and `v`, organized as column vectors. Similar data may be obtained via the code below:

```
N = 5;
[xf,yf,zf,vf] = flow(N);
ux = unique(xf);
uy = unique(yf);
uz = unique(zf);

x = nan(numel(xf),1);
y = nan(numel(yf),1);
z = nan(numel(zf),1);
v = nan(numel(vf),1);
iCount = 1;
for iX = 1:numel(ux)
    for iY = 1:numel(uy)
        for iZ = 1:numel(uz)
            x(iCount) = ux(iX);
            y(iCount) = uy(iY);
            z(iCount) = uz(iZ);
            v(iCount) = vf((xf == x(iCount))&(yf == y(iCount))&(zf == z(iCount)));
            iCount = iCount+1;
        end
    end
end
```

I could not change the way of data generation, so I need to reshape it to use later with `isosurface()` and `griddedInterpolant()` later. The size of the original data is rather big and I would like to avoid loops.
Simple usage of `reshape()` function:

```
X = reshape(x,[N,2*N,N]);
Y = reshape(y,[N,2*N,N]);
Z = reshape(z,[N,2*N,N]);
V = reshape(v,[N,2*N,N]);
isosurface(X,Y,Z,V,-3)
```

Shows me, that `Input grid is not a valid MESHGRID.`

**Could you help me to reshape the data in appropriate way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of items in your arrays doesn't match the column-major order that comes from `meshgrid`. You're almost done, but you need to reshape your 1d arrays with a different shape, then permute the result back to the actual shape you need:

```
N = 5;
[xf,yf,zf,vf] = flow(N);
ux = unique(xf);
uy = unique(yf);
uz = unique(zf);

x = nan(numel(xf),1);
y = nan(numel(yf),1);
z = nan(numel(zf),1);
v = nan(numel(vf),1);
iCount = 1;
for iX = 1:numel(ux)
    for iY = 1:numel(uy)
        for iZ = 1:numel(uz)
            x(iCount) = ux(iX);
            y(iCount) = uy(iY);
            z(iCount) = uz(iZ);
            v(iCount) = vf((xf == x(iCount))&(yf == y(iCount))&(zf == z(iCount)));
            iCount = iCount+1;
        end
    end
end

% new stuff starts here
X = permute(reshape(x,[N,N,2*N]),[2,3,1]);
Y = permute(reshape(y,[N,N,2*N]),[2,3,1]);
Z = permute(reshape(z,[N,N,2*N]),[2,3,1]);
V = permute(reshape(v,[N,N,2*N]),[2,3,1]);

% check equivalence
isequal(X,xf)
isequal(Y,yf)
isequal(Z,zf)
isequal(V,vf)
```

The above indicates that the input arrays are reproduced (we get four logical `1`s).

Note that your test case should be a bit more asymmetric, because now some of the input arrays are the transposes of one another, and two of the three dimensions have the same size. If your test with asymmetric sizes, i.e. `[N,M,K]`, it's much easier to figure out possible ambiguities, since all the dimensions are inequivalent in this case:

```
N = 2; M = 3; K = 4;
[xf,yf,zf] = meshgrid(1:N,1:M,1:K);
vf = flow(xf,yf,zf);

ux = unique(xf);
uy = unique(yf);
uz = unique(zf);

x = nan(numel(xf),1);
y = nan(numel(yf),1);
z = nan(numel(zf),1);
v = nan(numel(vf),1);
iCount = 1;
for iX = 1:numel(ux)
    for iY = 1:numel(uy)
        for iZ = 1:numel(uz)
            x(iCount) = ux(iX);
            y(iCount) = uy(iY);
            z(iCount) = uz(iZ);
            v(iCount) = vf((xf == x(iCount))&(yf == y(iCount))&(zf == z(iCount)));
            iCount = iCount+1;
        end
    end
end

X = permute(reshape(x,[K,M,N]),[2,3,1]);
Y = permute(reshape(y,[K,M,N]),[2,3,1]);
Z = permute(reshape(z,[K,M,N]),[2,3,1]);
V = permute(reshape(v,[K,M,N]),[2,3,1]);

% check equivalence
isequal(X,xf)
isequal(Y,yf)
isequal(Z,zf)
isequal(V,vf)
```